# How to test if a session already exists?

Tags: symfony

How can I test if a session exists in symfony?

Without the framework we proceed like this:

```
<?php

if( isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
  echo 'Bonjour '.$_SESSION['login'].' vous etes connecté.<br>';
}

?>
```

How to do so with the session service in the symfony controller with the Request object?

Comment: Are you interested in knowing if the session has started, or do you want to know if a user is authenticated?

Comment: i want to know if a session is already open, for example, when i access my homepage! if I'm already connected(session is already open) i go directly to my personal space, if not i will be redirected to the connexion page!! (excuse my bad ensglish)

Comment: Knowing wether the session is open or knowing if someone is logged in (so you can redirect to his personal space), are 2 entirely different questions. It appears to me you want to know if a user is authenticated though.

Comment: Exactly bro, this is what i wanted, and i solved the issue  by the jovan perovic andwer down !! thanks bro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Symfony, `session` service is an instance of `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session`. That said, `session` does provide several method to either check or manipulate session.

In your particular case, you would do something like this:

```
$session = $request->getSession();

if ( $session->has('login')){
    $message = 'Bonjour '.$session->get('login').' vous etes connecté.<br>';
}
```

But, noting the comment from @Gerry, **his question is a very valid one**.

Hope this helps...

Comment: While this seems to be what the OP wanted, I'd just like to point out this is not the proper way to check authentication/authorization, and in those cases the security component should be used instead of directly manipulating related session data.

Comment: @Gerry I could not agree more :)

Comment: @Gerry can you give me some tutorials about this part, because I'm a beginner at symfony so i dont know what you are truly talking about!!

Comment: @MouaadAitSaid start with the manual: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html

Comment: Watch out for `$request->hasSession()` ... from the API docs: "`This method does not give any information about the state of the session object,
     * like whether the session is started or not. It is just a way to check if this Request
     * is associated with a Session instance.`"

Comment: Good point. I never user `hasSession()` method myself thought, but `$session->isStarted()` instead